# I need to change the end date to 23:59:59 pm as opposed to 12 am

Tags: mysql

I am sending a date variable for start time and end time
The start time is find being automatically set to 12 am
However I need to end date to be set to 23:59:59

below are the code fragments that address the date:

```
IN fromDate varchar (50),
        IN toDate varchar (50),
        IN timeZone varchar (50))

    BEGIN
            DECLARE startDate varchar (50);
            DECLARE endDate varchar (50);
            DECLARE mylogID Int;

             SET startDate = FROM_UNIXTIME(fromDate/1000);
             SET endDate = FROM_UNIXTIME(toDate/1000);
```

This is the piece of code that actually calculates the time difference and here I need the endDate to be like 1/1/2013 11:59:59 pm as opposed to the default 1/1/2013 12:00 AM

```
time_to_sec(timediff(endDate, startDate)) / 3600 AS totalTimeRange
```

Comment: "the default?" There is no default here if you are using reasonable inputs... but dividing a VARCHAR by 1000 defies reason.  What do the fromDate and toDate input values look like? You may be getting an "almost correct" answer... by accident.

Comment: The division by 1000 is to convert the time passed as epoch to unix. That I know is correct. What I also know is that when I print the dates out from the query it prints at 12/21/2013 12:00 AM I need it to convert to 12/21/2013 23:59:59

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET endDate = DATE_SUB(FROM_UNIXTIME(toDate/1000),INTERVAL 1 SECOND);
```

That is the simple answer to your question.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub

...however... be sure you are fixing the correct problem.  Consider these two expressions: "before midnight tonight" and "at, or before, 23:59:59 tonight."  They seem equivalent if you are thinking in terms of integer timestamps, but as soon as fractional seconds enter the mix, the two expressions are distinctly not equivalent, because if you are using the latter one, and suddenly introduce milliseconds, you now have to say "at, or before, 23:59:59.999 tonight" ... while "before midnight tonight" is still as valid as it always was.

I am suggesting that if you are using `BETWEEN` with the ending timestamp as the second argument, or perhaps `<=` endDate, then the logically precise fix is not to subtract a second, but instead to use less-than comparison  `<` endDate.